# AUTOCAD Revolve a Polyline .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, autocad

I have a custom command which imports a 2D profile of a cutter. I then want to revolve the profile to create a 3D solid of the cutter. If I import a profile of only half of the cutter then the revolve works fine as it sits on one side of the revolve plane.

My issue is that I want to import the full cutter profile and somehow revolve it into the 3D solid. The problem is the center of the cutter profile is on the plane for revolving so it doesn’t work. Is there a way to calculate half of the profile region for revolving (or any other solution)?

I want to do this to avoid having 2 files representing the same cutter (one file with a full profile and another with half of the profile).

Hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

This is the full cutter profile.

[image]

This is the half cutter profile.

```
        <CommandMethod("RevolveObject")>
    Public Shared Sub RevolveObject()

        Dim doc As Document = AutoCADApp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
        Dim db As Database = doc.Database
        Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor

        Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()

            Dim pStrOpts As PromptStringOptions = New PromptStringOptions("FilePath: ")
            pStrOpts.AllowSpaces = True
            Dim FileName As PromptResult = ed.GetString(pStrOpts)

            Dim promptPointResult = ed.GetPoint(vbLf & "Specify point: ")
            If promptPointResult.Status <> PromptStatus.OK Then Return
            Dim Origin = promptPointResult.Value

            Dim ObjId As ObjectId
            Dim bt As BlockTable = db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead)
            Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace).GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)

            'Import the object
            Using dbInsert As New Database(False, True)
                dbInsert.ReadDwgFile(FileName.StringResult, IO.FileShare.Read, True, "")
                ObjId = db.Insert(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName.StringResult), dbInsert, True)
            End Using

            'Explode the object
            Dim acPoly As BlockReference = New BlockReference(New Point3d(Origin.X, Origin.Y, Origin.Z), ObjId)
            Dim acDBObjColl As DBObjectCollection = New DBObjectCollection()
            acPoly.Explode(acDBObjColl)

            'Revolve the object
            Dim pline As New Solid3d()
            Using plineCollection As New DBObjectCollection()
                plineCollection.Add(pline)
                Using regionCollection As DBObjectCollection = Region.CreateFromCurves(acDBObjColl)
                    Using region As Region = DirectCast(regionCollection(0), Region)
                        Using solid As New Solid3d()

                            solid.Layer = 0

                            Dim acVec3d As Vector3d = New Vector3d(0, 0, 10) 'not sure about the 10 but it works
                            solid.Revolve(region, Origin, acVec3d, 360 * (Math.PI / 180))

                            btr.AppendEntity(solid)
                            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(solid, True)

                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

            tr.Commit()

        End Using

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rotate the inserted block reference of 90° along X axis so that the revolution axis is parallel to the Z axis.

```
<CommandMethod("RevolveObject")>
Public Shared Sub RevolveObject()

    Dim doc As Document = AutoCADApp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
    Dim db As Database = doc.Database
    Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor

    Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()

        Dim pStrOpts As PromptStringOptions = New PromptStringOptions("FilePath: ")
        pStrOpts.AllowSpaces = True
        Dim FileName As PromptResult = ed.GetString(pStrOpts)

        Dim promptPointResult = ed.GetPoint(vbLf & "Specify point: ")
        If promptPointResult.Status <> PromptStatus.OK Then Return
        Dim Origin = promptPointResult.Value

        Dim ObjId As ObjectId
        Dim bt As BlockTable = db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead)
        Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace).GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)

        'Import the object
        Using dbInsert As New Database(False, True)
            dbInsert.ReadDwgFile(FileName.StringResult, IO.FileShare.Read, True, "")
            ObjId = db.Insert(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName.StringResult), dbInsert, True)
        End Using

        'Insert and rotate the object along X axis
        Dim acPoly As BlockReference = New BlockReference(Origin, ObjId)
        acPoly.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Rotation(Math.PI / 2.0, Vector3d.XAxis, Origin)
        
        'Explode the object
        Dim acDBObjColl As DBObjectCollection = New DBObjectCollection()
        acPoly.Explode(acDBObjColl)

        'Revolve the object
        Dim pline As New Solid3d()
        Using plineCollection As New DBObjectCollection()
            plineCollection.Add(pline)
            Using regionCollection As DBObjectCollection = Region.CreateFromCurves(acDBObjColl)
                Using region As Region = DirectCast(regionCollection(0), Region)
                    Using solid As New Solid3d()

                        solid.Layer = 0

                        Dim acVec3d As Vector3d = New Vector3d(0, 0, 10) 'not sure about the 10 but it works
                        solid.Revolve(region, Origin, acVec3d, 360 * (Math.PI / 180))

                        btr.AppendEntity(solid)
                        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(solid, True)

                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        tr.Commit()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @gileCAD. The cutter profiles are already oriented the correct way when they're imported to the modelspace (apologies for the misleading pictures showing the XY orientation). They are oriented along the Z axis. The problem is that full cutter profile cannot be revolved because the center of the cutter is along the revolve line. The half profile works because it is entirely on one side of the revolve line. That's why I was asking about possibly calculating half of the cutter profile region or even trimming the profile along the center and then revolving it.

Comment: It would be much more easy (and efficient) to use a block which contains only one directly usable Region for this purpose.